# Number of partitions was larger than BI Engine supports at this time Google Data Studio BI engine issue

Tags: looker-studio

I am using a BigQuery view to create a billing dashboard. Right now my dashboard is very slow and by looking BI engine support I found bellow error.

Number of partitions was larger than BI Engine supports at this time

Answer (score 0):

Currently, BigQuery BI Engine has limit on number of partitions in the table. For latest support please see https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/overview#limitations

Answer (score 0):

Maximum partitions per table (Looker Studio): `500 partitions`, BI Engine for Looker Studio supports up to a maximum of 500 partitions per table.

For latest update, checkout: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#biengine-limits